# I want to select rows(checkbox) in ag-grid based on a condition

Tags: checkbox, angular7, ag-grid-angular

Basically, there is a button which when clicked gets an array. I need to compare that array with existing ag-grid and if there is a match need to select the corresponding checkbox / rows. i.e.based on the combination. **Ag-grid and the array that we receive from the button has common keys that needs to be compared.**

Here, importExcel() gets an array on firing which is to be compared with the ag grid -

```
button class="btn btn-sm btn-secondary font-shrink pull-right" *ngIf='this.showUploadbtnSec' (click)="importExcel()" placement="top" 
                  tooltip="Upload now!" container="body">
                    <i class="lni-upload iconsize1"></i>
                  </button>
```

Ag-grid gridoptions

```
   public gridColumnDefs = [
        {
            headerName: 'Portfolio Name',
            field: 'portfolioName',
            cellRenderer: 'agGroupCellRenderer',
            headerCheckboxSelection: true,
            headerCheckboxSelectionFilteredOnly: true,
            checkboxSelection: true,
            pinned: 'left',
            filter: true
        },
]
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tired `isRowSelectable()`. It will always row selection based on some conditions.

[Is Row selectable](https://www.ag-grid.com/javascript-grid-selection/#specify-selectable-rows)